# Jqgrid implementation in Spring

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jqgrid

I have to display data on table, I choosed [Jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php) for that. But I am stucked by **500 Internal Server Error issue** on response URL.

Here is my implementation details:

**Controller**: 
Approach 1:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/allCase", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody void getAllSearchCases(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response){
        LOG.info("Inside SearchCaseController#getAllSearchCases method.");
        try {
            response.getWriter().write(searchCaseServiceImpl.getAllSearchCaseAsJsonObject().toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.info("Error while writing data on response: Error inside class: {}, Caused by: {}", e.getClass(), e.getCause());
        }
    }
```

Approach 2:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/allCase", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody JSONObject getAllSearchCases(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response){
        LOG.info("Inside SearchCaseController#getAllSearchCases method.");
        return searchCaseServiceImpl.getAllSearchCaseAsJsonObject();
    }
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
$("#case-table").jqGrid({
        url : getAllCases,
        datatype : "json",
        width : jqgridwidth,
        loadui : 'disable',
        colNames : [ 'Case Id', 'Created By', 'Created Date', 'Search Key', 'Status', 'Action' ],
        colModel : [ {
            name : 'caseId',
            index : 'caseId',
            sorttype : "int",
            align : "left",
            width : 300,
        }, {
            name : 'Created By',
            index : 'createdBy',
            sorttype : "text",
            align : "left",
        }, {
            name : 'createdDate',
            index : 'createdDate',
            sorttype : "date",
            align : "left",
        }, {
            name : 'searchKey',
            index : 'searchKey',
            sorttype : "text",
            align : "left",
        }, {
            name : 'status',
            index : 'status',
            sorttype : "text",
            align : "left",
            classes : "pk-word-wrap",
        },{
            name : 'action',
            index : 'action',
            sorttype : "text",
            align : "left",
            classes : "pk-word-wrap",
        }, ],
        jsonReader : {
            root : "rows",
            page : "page",
            total : "total",
            records : "records",
            repeatitems : true,
            cell : "cell",
            id : "id",
        },
        cmTemplate : {
            resizable : false
        },
        loadComplete : function () {
        },
        rowNum : 100,
        beforeSelectRow : function ( id ) {

        },
        ignoreCase : true,
        height : "auto",
        pager : '#pagingDiv',
        sortname : 'caseId',
        viewrecords : true,
        loadonce : true,
        sortorder : "desc",
        recordpos : 'left',
        emptyrecords : "No Case Available",
        cellEdit : true,
    });
```

**Error is:** 
[image]

Can you guys help me to figure out what is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you inspect the servers logs for the exception causing the problem?

Comment: I can't see any log on server side. I mean it is not causing exception on server side.

Comment: You need to enable logging in your spring app.

Comment: Where should I add "log4j.category.org.springframework=ALL" property? I am unable to get log on Error level. I guess i am missing some log of error level.

Comment: We are using log4J for logging.